# Can I enter France from outside the Schengen area with a valid permesso di soggiorno?

Tags: schengen, france, permesso-di-soggiorno

I get a *récépissé* while waiting for my France *carte de séjour*. I also have Italian *permesso di soggiorno* that's valid until 03/08/2021. Is it possible to enter France from an Asian country with *permesso di soggiorno* that's nearly expired? I will arrive in France on 02/08/2021, one day before my *permesso di soggiorno* expires.

Answer (score -3):

Edit based on the comment: I'm assuming that you requested your titre de séjour outside of France (from Italy or the Asian country you are currently in), so you'll be travelling into France for residence purposes and not returning to it after a period of absence

Your *récépissé* should allow you to enter France on its own as long as it is valid

> Le récépissé est un document attestant du dépôt de votre demande de titre de séjour à la préfecture (ou sous-préfecture) de votre domicile. Il vous autorise à séjourner en France pour la durée qu'il précise.

Source: https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F15763

Comment: (-1) That's not what the quoted text says, it merely says that a *récépissé* allows you to *stay* in France. In fact, a *récépissé* for the first application (as opposed to a renewal) explicitely does *not* allow you to leave and reenter, you need a *visa de retour* for that. Thus the OP would not rely on the *récépissé* but on the *permesso di soggiorno*. The question here is whether there is a risk that having left the territory would have an effect on the application or an issue related to the looming expiration of the Italian perrmit.

Comment: @Relaxed That's a good point - I'm assuming that OP lived in Italy, went to Asia temporarily and then applied for residence in France

Comment: That sounds about right but either way the *récépissé* doesn't help.

Comment: @Relaxed thank you very much. You got my point clearly. This is the one that I am afraid. If I am possible to leave France territory and re enter France using the permesso di soggiorno (Italy permit). I don't find a clear explanation about this in the government website. Thanks for help. So I am still not getting the direct answer for my question. Thanks to anyone who gave comments:)